# Отслеживание нажатия кнопки в electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

Есть div который содержит в себе еще два div, один с иконкой а другой с текстом, сделал таким способом реакцию на нажатие

```
addEventListener('click', event => {
    onClick(event.srcElement.id);
});

function onClick(id){
    console.log(id);
}
```

при нажатии на div все ок, в консоль выводится id этого div, но если нажать на иконку или текст, выводится id иконки или текста. Но ведь функция вызвалась, а привязана она к нажатию не иконки или текста, а div. Как отследить конкретно id этого div без jQuery и т.д и т.п?

Comment: Можно написать обыкновенную функцию, которая выводит id, и эту функцию задать значением атрибута onclick у вашего div. Возможно, это не сработает.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: onClick is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Comment: видимо потому что функция в renderer.js. перенес в main.js - тоже самое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по коду событие привязано совсем не к div, а к window. Повесьте событие на div.addEventListener, а вместо event.srcElement.id используйте div.id

Comment: с одним div это работает но у меня есть еще 5 таких div с одинаковым классом и разными id. я сделал так: ```var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('div');
for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].addEventListener('click', event => {
        onClick(divs[i].id);
    });
}``` но тогда происходит Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: const divs = [...document.querySelectorAll('.div')];

    divs.forEach(div => {
        div.addEventListener('click', e => onClick(div.id));
    });

Comment: спасибо, теперь работает корректно